# h2 protocol error: http2 error: stream error received: stream no longer needed

Tags: database, cnosdb

I want to collect cnosdb logs through vector, and then write them into the cnosdb database.the report waring:

```
2023-08-16T06:09:05.269786Z  WARN sink{component_kind="sink" component_id=cnosdb component_type=vector component_name=cnosdb}:request{request_id=1}: vector::sinks::util::retries: Retrying after error. error=Request failed: status: Cancelled, message: "h2 protocol error: http2 error: stream error received: stream no longer needed", details: [], metadata: MetadataMap { headers: {} } internal_log_rate_limit=true
2023-08-16T06:09:06.317381Z  WARN sink{component_kind="sink" component_id=cnosdb component_type=vector component_name=cnosdb}:request{request_id=1}: vector::sinks::util::retries: Internal log [Retrying after error.] is being suppressed to avoid flooding.
```

and check the database,there was no table find.

I modified the output position of the sink, and the screen output is normal

my vector config is :

```
data_dir = "/var/lib/vector"

# Random Syslog-formatted logs
[sources.logs]
type = "file"
include = [ "/tmp/cnosdb/1001/log/tsdb.log.2023-08-14" ]

# Parse Syslog logs
# See the Vector Remap Language reference for more info: https://vrl.dev
[transforms.parse_logs]
type = "remap"
inputs = ["logs"]
source = '''
#. = split!(.message, " ")
#. = parse_common_log!(.message)
. = parse_regex!(.message, r'^(?P<time>.+?)\s+(?P<level>\w+)\s+(?P<compont>.+?):\s+(?P<message>.+)$')
# . = string!(.message)
# . = parse_syslog!(string!(.message))
._tenant = "cnosdb"
._database = "public"
# ._table = "vector_log_test"
._table = "cnosdb_log_test"
._user = "root"
._password = ""

'''

# Print parsed logs to stdout
#[sinks.print]
#type = "console"
# inputs = ["parse_logs"]
# encoding.codec = "json"


[sinks.cnosdb]
type = "vector"
inputs = ["parse_logs"]
address = "127.0.0.1:12006"
```

So waht's wrong with the config?